# How to calculate fibonacci-sequence for String data set?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, fibonacci, memoization

I want to calculate Fibonacci sequence for a string data set. I'm writing a normal JavaScript function but I want to write the code using the latest ECMAScript features.

```js
var message = "The Da Vinci Code is a 2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown";

function FibonacciSecret(message) {
  var s = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    s += message.replace(/\s+/g, '').substr(getNthValue(i), 1).toUpperCase();
    if (i != 9) {
      s += "-";
    }
  }

  function getNthValue(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
      return n;
    }
    if (n > 1) {
      return getNthValue(n - 1) + getNthValue(n - 2);
    }
  }
  return s;
}

console.log(FibonacciSecret(message)); // "T-H-H-E-D-V-C-E-M-T"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Memoization

Instead of calculate every time the `n` number of *fibonacci* you can simple look it up in a table if you calculated it once. This is called *Memoization*. You can read more about it in [Faster JavaScript Memoization](https://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/) by Addy Osmani.

## Your Code

The function `getNthValue` gets defined every time you call `FibonacciSecret`. It may be would have a better performance if you would define it outside, but I did't test it. But it would be definitely better to test your code.

Additionally on each iteration you remove whitspaces `message.replace(/\s+/g, '')` and call `toUpperCase`but one call would be enough.

## Example

I wrote it recursively because I think the code is easier to read. I pass in String without whitespaces (`createSecretString(messageWithoutWhitespace, memory, secret)` and save on each recursion a letter in `secret`. On the last recursion I return the array joined to a string and upper case all letters once. (`secret.join('-').toUpperCase()`)

```js
const message = "The Da Vinci Code is a 2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown";
const fibonacciMemory = {}

function fibonacci(x, memory = {}) {
  if (memory[x]) {
    return memory[x]
  }
  if (x < 1) {
    return 0
  }
  if (x <= 2) {
    return 1
  }
  return memory[x] = fibonacci(x - 1, memory) + fibonacci(x - 2, memory);
}

function createSecretString(message, memory, secret) {
  const length = secret.length - 1
  return length < 10 
    ? createSecretString(message, memory, secret.concat(message.substr(fibonacci(length, memory), 1))) 
    : secret.join('-').toUpperCase()
}

function fibonacciSecret(message, memory, secret = []) {
  const messageWithoutWhitespace = message.replace(/\s+/g, '')
  return createSecretString(messageWithoutWhitespace, memory, secret)
}

console.log(fibonacciSecret(message, fibonacciMemory))
```

#### "Benchmark"

with memoization

```js
const message = "The Da Vinci Code is a 2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown";
const fibonacciMemory = {}

function fibonacci(x, memory = {}) {
  if (memory[x]) {
    return memory[x]
  }
  if (x < 1) {
    return 0
  }
  if (x <= 2) {
    return 1
  }
  return memory[x] = fibonacci(x - 1, memory) + fibonacci(x - 2, memory);
}

function createSecretString(message, memory, secret) {
  const length = secret.length - 1
  return length < 10 
    ? createSecretString(message, memory, secret.concat(message.substr(fibonacci(length, memory), 1))) 
    : secret.join('-').toUpperCase()
}

function fibonacciSecret(message, memory, secret = []) {
  const messageWithoutWhitespace = message.replace(/\s+/g, '')
  return createSecretString(messageWithoutWhitespace, memory, secret)
}

const t0 = performance.now();
fibonacciSecret(message, fibonacciMemory);
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log("First call took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

var t2 = performance.now();
fibonacciSecret(message, fibonacciMemory);
var t3 = performance.now();
console.log("Second call took " + (t3 - t2) + " milliseconds.");
```

without memoization

```js
var message = "The Da Vinci Code is a 2003 mystery-detective novel by Dan Brown";

function FibonacciSecret(message){
  var s = '';
   for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   s += message.replace(/\s+/g,'').substr(getNthValue(i), 1).toUpperCase();
   if(i != 9) {
       s += "-";
      }
   }

   function getNthValue(n) {
   if(n <= 1) {
       return n;
      }
   if(n > 1) {
       return getNthValue(n-1) + getNthValue(n-2);
      }
   }
   return s;
}

var t0 = performance.now();
FibonacciSecret(message);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```